# SQL solution for Single Identity from Multiple IDs

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I am looking for a way, via SQL, to establish a single `visitor_id` from rows that share common (but different) keys and then produce an output table assigning the established `visitor_id` back to all of the rows.
 My Database is AWS Athena.

Example:

```
with things as (
    select 'aaa' as thing_id, '111' as visitor_id, 'alpha@gmail.com' as email_address, '(111) 111-1111' as phone_number
    union all select 'bbb' as thing_id, '111' as visitor_id, 'beta@gmail.com' as email_address, null as phone_number
    union all select 'ccc' as thing_id, '111' as visitor_id, null as email_address, '(222) 222-2222' as phone_number
    union all select 'ddd' as thing_id, '222' as visitor_id, 'alpha@gmail.com' as email_address, '(333) 333-3333' as phone_number
    union all select 'eee' as thing_id, '333' as visitor_id, 'alpha@gmail.com' as email_address, null as phone_number
    union all select 'fff' as thing_id, '444' as visitor_id, 'charlie@gmail.com' as email_address, '(333) 333-3333' as phone_number
    union all select 'ggg' as thing_id, '555' as visitor_id, 'charlie@gmail.com' as email_address, '(444) 444-4444' as phone_number
    union all select 'hhh' as thing_id, '666' as visitor_id, null as email_address, '(444) 444-4444' as phone_number

)
```

I know that all of these things belong to the same `visitor_id` as

- `aaa`, `bbb`, and `ccc` all share the same `visitor_id`
- `ddd` and `eee` share the same `email_address` as `aaa`, `bbb`, and `ccc`
- `fff` shares the same `phone_number` as `ddd` (and thus is the same `vistior_id` as `aaa`)
- `ggg` shares the same `email_address` as `fff` (and thus is the same `vistior_id`  as `fff` which is the same `visitor_id` as `aaa`)
- `hhh` shares the same `phone_number` as `ggg` (and thus is the same `vistior_id` as `ggg` which is the same as `aaa`)

My desired output table would be:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      thing_id       |     vistior_id   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         aaa         |        111       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         bbb         |        111       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         ccc         |        111       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         ddd         |        111       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         eee         |        111       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         fff         |        111       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         ggg         |        111       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         hhh         |        111       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I have tried cross joining and then eliminating duplicates. However, I am struggling with `fff`, `ggg`, and `hhh`, as they are only related to `aaa` through the other `thing_id`s

Comment: This requires a recursive CTE or hierarchical query.  What database are you using?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Alternative is to use a graph database. Anything connected is part of the same ID.

Comment: I am using AWS Athena